# How to remove script tags?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, css

On my website I have tags that people can use to post on my site and mess with it. 
What I would like to know is how do i make it so the browser just reviews everything in a 
file I write too as text.
I would like it so there is no html and in certian parts of my website!

### All of it is in ASP

Comment: Please rephrase your question - I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://htmlpurifier.org/.  It filters HTML input with a white list of acceptable tags, so you don't get anything undesirable - like iframes, or javascript, etc.  Assuming I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The general term for what you are asking for is "HTML Sanitization" - There is actually a good discussion of this, along with some code on the [StackOverflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/).